# When are two unlabelled simple graphs considered equal?

Tags: graph-theory, recurrence-relations, graph-isomorphism, decision-problems

When are two unlabelled simple (not necessarily connected) graphs considered equal? I don't really find a way to formally state this.

Additionally, what might be a way to find the number of unlabelled simple graphs (not necessarily connected)? I understand that there isn't a closed form. Is there any recursion or something of that sort which can evaluate this (in some manner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question

> When are two unlabelled simple (not necessarily connected) graphs considered equal?

to systematically determine when two such graphs are equal (isomorphic) you label both of them
and try possible bijections between the nodes. If no such bijection is a
[graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism), 
then the two graphs are not equal.

The [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem)
is very difficult in general. It is often easier to determine
when two graphs are **not** equal. For example, if they have different
[degree sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence)
then they are not equal.

For your second question

> Additionally, what might be a way to find the number of unlabelled simple graphs (not necessarily connected)?

the [OEIS sequence A000088](https://oies.org/A000088) is "Number of graphs on n unlabeled nodes" and it has some Mathematica and PARI/GP code that computes the sequence.

Comment: $G = \{A,B,C,D\}$ be a graph such that $(A,B)$ and $(A,C)$ are edges. Had $(B,C)$ and $(B,A)$ been edges instead and the graph was unlabelled, the two would have been considered same. But if $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ were the connections (for instance), they would have been different. Right?

Comment: @Mathejunior In your first two cases, one node has two edges connected to it. In the last case, each node is connected to exactly one edge.

Comment: Exactly. I just stated an example which is glaringly obvious. Thank you so much for the formalization.